# Android Q (10) - The app icon is not displayed while the app is backgrounded in the stack of apps

Tags: android, android-10.0

QA team reported the bug on Pixel2 XL android Q (10) - The app icon is not displayed while the app is in background in the stack of apps (recents).

In the app used an adaptive icon created through 'Image Asset'. On previous Android versions - all good. But some times after the setup app through Google Play (or directly from an android studio) - app icon is not displayed when the app is backgrounded in the stack of apps. It happened not always.

[wrong behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j80Of.jpg)

[right behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1yZG.jpg)

For test was created default empty project with an **adaptive icon** (with legacy icons and icons for any dpi-v26). Bug reproduced. Also on the emulator with android 10.

In manifest:

```
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
    .....
```

Renaming app icons and other solutions don't help.

**Update:**
I think it is a system bug. Because default apps like calendar have the same issues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you able to put a screenshot hierarchy of your res directory from src->main?

Comment: @Dhaval Solanki, hierarchy looks like on your screenshot below.

Answer (score 5):

The issue because of somewhere else this icon exists which shown in your **wrong behavior**  So just check is there any icon exists with wrong design which is.

Like in my case here two directories which contain icon with different background, So I am deleting the icon from this directory or otherwise, I delete this two directory and its work fine(**Note: Don't delete directory go on explore and then delete.**).

```
mipmap-anydpi-v26  
drawable-v24
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Dhaval Solanki. But this breaks the principle of adaptive icons. I also thought that somewhere there is such an icon and made a rename. Not help.

Comment: Okay then go inside adaptive icon background just change color it will also work..

Comment: very strange. As I noted above, sometimes the correct icon appears. For example, after restarting the device. On emulators - all good. On Pixel 2 XL - happening something strange.

Comment: Actually may be this issue not arise because of rstart or something like that but its arise because of device API version or configuration..

Comment: I've changed also the foreground icon. But nothing helps. The app icon successfully changed. But on top in 'app stack' state showing default icon with white android head and blue background.

Comment: Then i just suggest ad another adptive icon from add image asset and try..

Comment: For that case was created a new empty project with the new app icon. All the same wrong behavior. Maybe you're right: 'its arise because of device API version or configuration..'

Comment: I think no need to create new project you can create replace adaptive icon

Comment: Replaced. Not help.

Comment: how did you fix this ? i am facing same issue

Comment: @Richa Unfortunately we haven't been able to fix this yet.

Comment: @vicmikhailau : try to create icons from adaptive icons and you are good to go.

Comment: @Richa in the question above icons was created from adaptive icons. I think it is a system bug. Because default apps like calendar have the same issues.

Comment: @vicmikhailau for me only for few devices this issue is happening

Comment: @vicmikhailau were you able to fix it? I am having the same issue on Android 10, API level 29

Comment: @CapeAndCowl all icons was created through adaptive icons. In some cases by first and other random app launch - icon showed. But in the future - disappeared.

Comment: @CapeAndCowl i had the same problem. turn off/on phone and should be ok

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on real device, using Android 10 API level 29. Renaming the icons also did not fix it.

The solution I figured is to use new "adaptive icons". What this will basically do is generate adaptive icons which are not covered in the `mimap` folders. Use the following steps:

1. Go to `android/app/src/main/res/` folder of your project
2. Create `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder if it does not exist.
3. Create an `xml` file inside `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder. This `xml` file should be named exactly same as the string you are using for your icon name. For example, by default the name of icon string is `ic_launcher`, so name this `xml` as `ic_launcher.xml`.
4. The `xml` should have the following lines, nothing else. You can paste these if you have made a new file in step 3. Make sure that you have `_background` and `_foreground` postfixes to the names as shown below. If you don't have these and just use `@mipmap/ic_launcher` for both background and foreground, it won't work.

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

5. Go to https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html and first customize the background. I just used a white background. Before downloading, make sure that you name it as `ic_launcher_background`. Do the same for foreground using whatever image you need as foreground in icon and download it with the name `ic_launcher_foreground`.
6. Extract the downloaded zip files, and copy the `res` folders one by one to `android/app/src/main/res/`.
7. So now you should have 2 new files in each `mimap` folder with for foreground and background.
8. Rebuild and run the project to see changes.

Comment: Thanks, @CapeAndCowl. But as I have already described in the question and in the comments - the project uses adaptive icons from the very beginning.
Note: all steps described above will be changed like this:
Click on the 'res' folder -> new->Image Asset.

Comment: @vicmikhailau I was not getting the option for Image Assets in Android studio on Linux, so I had to go through this lengthy process. In your case is the bug present on just Pixel2 XL, or any other devices as well? And is it the same behaviour in both emulator and real device?
Just to add: I do not have a drawable-v24 folder

Comment: It's clear. Reproduced on Xiaomi MIA3, Samsung S10+. All with Android 10. Some times icon showed. But through the time disappeared.

Comment: also, don't forget to restart your device, uninstalling the app is not enough. My emulator did not show the icon until I restarted it